# Sorting Posts by Custom Field is not working properly in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I have WordPress posts and I have Boolean Advanced Custom Field for each, which changes the status of being featured for each university post. So when outputting them, I want to show the featured ones (more clearly, the ones which have the featured field set to true) first. But when I'm doing it, WordPress is showing me 8 posts, but not 10 (as I wrote), even though I have enough posts. What can be causing the issue?

```php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'university', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'meta_key' => 'featured', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => 'DESC' 
);
```

I tried browsing and asking ChatGPT, but I didn't find any working solution yet.

Comment: Do you need `'meta_value' => true,` in the query as well?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see what you mean. I tried this as well, but it's showing only featured posts this way. I need 10 posts with the featured ones appearing on top.

Comment: Did you visit the posts where your boolean is false and Update them?  If you haven't done that yet, then they don't have any value saved for this meta field and won't be included in the query.

Comment: @ChadPhillips I visited all posts and certain posts have it set to false and some of them are set to true.

Comment: Please try this: for the post_id of a post where you have the featured meta value set to true, but it isn't showing in your list, call $meta = get_post_meta($post_id); and then print_r($meta); Add the output to your answer, just to demonstate that this meta value is indeed set.

Answer (score 0):

In a WordPress query, if you order by a meta_value, posts that do not have this meta_value set will be excluded from the results.  Even if you set the default value of a boolean custom field to false, this value is not set on a post until you update that post.  So, you have to open all posts and save a value (true or false) for this meta_value, or run a script to set this value on all posts where you haven't yet set a value.

Comment: In each post, I see the field is set to false or to true. I tried to re-update their value but it still doesn't show up.